# TSQL Slow Query, not using index as expected

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, azure-sql-database, index-tuning

I have a wide table, relatively large, 14,264,775 rows, running on Azure SQL database.

The following query is in need of some TLC.

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT  1/0 
    FROM dbo.table1 src
      INNER JOIN dbo.table1 tgt 
        ON tgt.Col1 = src.Col1
    WHERE tgt.ValidFrom <= src.ValidTo
    AND tgt.ValidTo >= src.ValidFrom
    AND tgt.RecordId <> src.RecordId  
)
 BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Overlap detected in dbo.table1', 11, 1); 
 END ;
```

I have this index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX__table1] ON dbo.table1
        ( Col1 ) 
INCLUDE (ValidFrom, ValidTo, RecordId)
GO
```

This is the io stats from the query. The logical reads are through the roof.

[image]

Here's the [plan XML](https://textdoc.co/ofxdQpaWEkwR109T).
I tried PasteThePlan but it wouldn't parse the plan XML. (perhaps it doesn't like Axure sql database plan xml).

As you can see there's an index scan on [src] ; reading 14,264,775 rows (the same number as all the rows in the table) . And an index seek on [tgt] ; reading 194,405,307 rows.

What do I need to change to improve the performance of the query?

There are 2.1 million unique Col1 values amongst the 14 million total rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to have manually edited the XML and made it invalid, primarily by adding invalid characters like `<` and `>`. After fixing some issues, I was able to load the plan into SSMS and Plan Explorer:

[image: Plan]

This shows you have an index named `[IX__dbo_table1__DateRange]`—not mentioned in the question. Judging by the seek predicate, this index has at least `Col1` and `ValidTo` in the index keys.

Another problem is the use of `IF EXISTS`. This introduces a [row goal](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.html), which causes the optimizer to favour a nested loops solution. See the related Q & A [IF EXISTS taking longer than embedded select statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/126235/1192).

That said, finding any possible overlapping range is a difficult problem to solve completely with a b-tree index, see [Resolving a performance issue with BETWEEN join - eager spool](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/149805/1192).

Without knowing the complete table definition, indexes, and data distribution it's difficult to suggest a proper solution. If you just want something quick and easy to try without changing the indexes or source query too much, try a hash join hint:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT  1/0 
    FROM dbo.table1 src
      INNER HASH JOIN dbo.table1 tgt -- hint added
        ON tgt.Col1 = src.Col1
    WHERE tgt.ValidFrom <= src.ValidTo
    AND tgt.ValidTo >= src.ValidFrom
    AND tgt.RecordId <> src.RecordId  
)
 BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Overlap detected in dbo.table1', 11, 1); 
 END ;
```

This will fully scan the index twice, but this may not be too bad if your system can handle the memory or I/O requirements, and if parallelism or [batch mode execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing-details#batch-mode-on-rowstore) is available. This will work best if there are a decent number of different `Col1` values.

[image: Parallel batch mode hash join plan]

Assuming overlaps should be disallowed, my preference would be to avoid the situation occurring in the first place using constraints. See [What is the correct way to ensure unique entries in a temporal database design?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/64862/1192)

---

Or, as [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) suggested in chat:

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1/0
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            T.ValidFrom,
            PrevValidTo =
                LAG(T.ValidTo) OVER ( 
                    PARTITION BY T.Col1
                    ORDER BY T.ValidFrom)
        FROM dbo.table1 AS T
    ) AS T1
    WHERE 
        T1.PrevValidTo >= T1.ValidFrom
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Overlap detected in dbo.table1', 11, 1); 
END;
```

With an index like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX__table1] 
ON dbo.table1
    (Col1, ValidFrom) 
INCLUDE 
    (ValidTo, RecordId);
```

[image: Window function solution]

Answer (score 0):

Currently all records will be read because you are querying the records where tgt.Col1 = src.Col1, which is the complete table.

You should make the index more selective by adding `ValidFrom` and/or `ValidTo` to the index.

When adding those to the index, that columns can be removed after the INCLUDE parts.